# Ordinary or Partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[Pic of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X05RQ.png)

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$$
I saw this in an imageboard site and it bothers me. OP said it's a valid equation, if so then $y$ is constant. But in that format, doesn't it violates the rule for partial derivative, where it should have a one dependent variable and two or more independent variables. So it lingers me to say that it may be an ODE.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=2\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

Comment: So you think that the equation is wrong? What if the function y is constant?

Comment: In your equation there is only one variable $x$. So it is an ODE. If it was a PDE at least one other variable would be involved. What is the other variable ?

Comment: If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a typo in the equation
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$$
If the equation was a correct PDE at least two variables would be involved for example $x$ and $t$. The PDE would be :
$$2\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$$
Writting $y(x,t)$ makes clear that a second variable exists and makes clear what is its name.

Then the general solution is not $y=$constant but is :
$$y(x,t)=f(t)$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary function. The case $y=f(t)=$constant is not the general solution but is only a particular solution.

However all the above is without interest. Most probably the PDE without typo is :
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=0$$
and the general solution would be $\quad y=F(x-t)\quad$ where $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).